# Speaking about me takes you back

Tags: wordplay

When you say that I'm feathery, that's quite clearly wrong.
If I come from the trees then you can join me in song.

I've nothing to wag, but you imply that I do.
I have nothing to sell, but you suggest that's untrue.

You say I'm unwell if I give you no prize.
If you ensnare me I'll bring tears to your eyes.

You say that I'm angry when I turn to the side.
But call me divine and you'd better all hide.

**Question:** Who or what am I?

Comment: Seems to me like it's some sort of weather event

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Wind

I think the title refers to

> Rewind or "Re: wind", "Re" being an abbreviation for "in re" meaning "in response to" implying a subject about which you wish to speak.

When you say that I'm feathery, that's quite clearly wrong.

> Could refer to "downwind" not being feathery (credit to deepthought in the comments)

If I come from the trees then you can join me in song.

> Referring to woodwind musical instruments

I've nothing to wag, but you imply that I do.

> A tailwind is one that comes from behind.

I have nothing to sell, but you suggest that's untrue.

> Referring to "trade" winds (thanks to deepthought for pointing this out)

You say I'm unwell if I give you no prize.

> "It's an ill wind that blows nobody any good"

If you ensnare me I'll bring tears to your eyes.

> Trapped wind can make you cry

You say that I'm angry when I turn to the side.

> A "cross" wind (crosswind) comes from the side

But call me divine and you'd better all hide.

> The Japanese word Kamikaze translates as "divine wind"

Thanks to the commenters for their help especially deepthought who sorted out two of the lines.

Comment: @deepthought, yes trade wind works much better, thank you.

Comment: Line 1 could refer to the phrase "wind on your wing" or "wind beneath your wings"?

Comment: @Gordon K, I've figured out the 2nd line and edited the 4th line with deepthought's suggestion. Not sure about the 1st

Comment: @deepthought so a feathery wind could be a 'down' wind but is that "wrong" as the line suggests?

Comment: I think they mean "downwind" (i.e., downwind does not mean 'feathery wind')

Comment: Just the title to crack, then.

Comment: Okay, sorted the title, thanks guys!

Comment: Aha, "crack"! The wind "speaks" through the "crack" in your "back"(side)....... no? Ah well can't get them all.

Comment: Lol I was thinking 'flute' as the answer. :D